# Desktop not responding after restart

Tags: motherboard

I have an old PC with the following specs:

**Compaq Presario SR1200IL**

- MoBo: ASUS Kelute (a7v8x-la)
- Chipset: VIA KM400A
- Processor: AMD Athlon XP

The system is working (sometimes), but when I restart sometime after usage, not even the POST screen is showing, the monitor is going to sleep mode as no signal on dispaly, the keyboard lights are not working etc..
Instead the HDD light is turned on continuously.
It is related to HDD because I disconnected all drives (CD, floppy, HDD).
There is no sound coming from the PC at this point. But all the fans are working.
But the PC speakers are working because when I removed RAM, the system is beeping.

Even after I restarted the system by completely disconnecting power, the issue persists. But After 4-5hrs I am able to use the system.

I am not able to figure out what the issue is.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the motherboard isn't even completing POST, there's a hardware fault somewhere _(either an issue with hardware or a cable not seated properly)_.  Have you tried booting into the hardware diagnostics to run a basic and extended test?  Have you pulled the HDD to run a S.M.A.R.T test on a different non-Windows PC using `smartctl` (contained within the package `smartmontools`)?

Comment: Actually it is working perfectly when I turn it on after 4-5 hrs, and everything works also I removed HDD and tested, the issue is still there. I dont think it is due to HDD.

Comment: I changed the thermal paste also, just to make sure it is not an issue with the heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the internal modem and the issue gets resolved.